# Laravel 7 blade view @guest and Auth::user problem

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

I have a button in my nav, if you are a @guest is a link to a connection modal and @else i have two kinds of display in function of the Auth user role but i see only the @esle display!

In local with Valet everything work's fine this problem is just when i deploy the project on web.

```
                  @guest
                    <li class="nav-item ml-2">
                        <a class="nav-link text-success" id="conModal" href="" data-toggle="modal"
                           data-target="#connexionTarget">{{ __('Connexion') }}</a>
                    </li>
                    @else
                    @if(Auth::user()->role_id === 0)
                        <li class="nav-item ml-2 dropdown">
                            <a id="navbarDropdown" class="nav-link dropdown-toggle text-success" href="#" role="button"
                               data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" v-pre>
                                {{ Auth::user()->firstName }} <span class="caret"></span>
                            </a>

                            <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
                                <a class="dropdown-item linkCollapse infoUserBtn" href="" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#infoUser">
                                    {{ __('Mon Profil') }}
                                </a>
                                <a class="dropdown-item linkCollapse userOrdersBtn" href="" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#userOrders">
                                    {{ __('Mes Commandes') }}
                                </a>
                                <a class="dropdown-item" href="{{ route('logout') }}"
                                   onclick="event.preventDefault();
                                                         document.getElementById('logout-form').submit();">
                                    {{ __('Déconnection') }}
                                </a>

                                <form id="logout-form" action="{{ route('logout') }}" method="POST"
                                      style="display: none;">
                                    @csrf
                                </form>
                            </div>
                        </li>
                    @else
                        <li class="nav-item ml-2 dropdown">
                            <a id="navbarDropdown" class="nav-link dropdown-toggle text-success" href="#" role="button"
                               data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" v-pre>
                                {{ Auth::user()->firstName }} <span class="caret"></span>
                            </a>

                            <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
                                <a class="dropdown-item" href="{{ route('logout') }}"
                                   onclick="event.preventDefault();
                                                         document.getElementById('logout-form').submit();">
                                    {{ __('Déconnection') }}
                                </a>
                                <form id="logout-form" action="{{ route('logout') }}" method="POST"
                                      style="display: none;">
                                    @csrf
                                </form>
                            </div>
                        </li>
                    @endif
                    @endguest
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check Laravel Documentation from here [Control Structures](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/blade#control-structures) >> Authentication Directives

The @auth and @guest directives may be used to quickly determine if the current user is authenticated or is a guest:

```
@auth
    // The user is authenticated...
@endauth

@guest
    // The user is not authenticated...
@endguest
```